# Matlab - Generate square convex function with positive definite Hessian Matrix

Tags: matrices, functions, convex-analysis, matlab

So, I have to generate a square convex function in Matlab and it's Hessian Matrix must be positive definite but I can't find any function that can help me do that.

Is there anything I should search for or I simply think it and insert it from my keyboard?

Comment: Do you know the function you want to implement? Or do yo need help finding such a function? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: I need help finding such a function.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

- Generate a random symmetric matrix (Matlab: rand)
- Do an eigenvalue decomposition (Matlab: eig), returning an orthogonal matrix $U$
- Generate a random, positive vector and put it on the diagonal of $\Sigma$
- $U^\top \, \Sigma \, U$ is a random, symmetric, positive definite matrix with eigenvectors from $U$ and eigenvalues from $\Sigma$.

Comment: +1: nice idea, constructing a unitary matrix that way. I would change notation, though. To me it is best to say that $U$ is *orthogonal* rather than unitary, to make it clear that it is real.